# Store references to self

Tags: rust, weak-references

I am trying to create a network of nodes in Rust, where I want every node in the network to be aware of every other connected node. I thought that this could be done with weak `Rc`'s, like this:

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::rc::Weak;

struct Node {
    name: String,
    known_nodes: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Weak<Node>>>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn connect_to_network(&mut self) {
        self.known_nodes
            .borrow_mut()
            .push(Rc::downgrade(&Rc::new(*self)));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let known_nodes = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));
    let node_one = Node {
        name: "node1",
        known_nodes: known_nodes.copy(),
    };
    node_one.connect_to_network();
    let node_two = Node {
        name: "node2",
        known_nodes: known_nodes.copy(),
    };
    node_two.connect_to_network();
}
```

This however yields

> cannot move out of borrowed content

at:

```
self.known_senders.borrow_mut().push(Rc::downgrade(&Rc::new(*self)));
```

Because `*self` is moved out of borrowed content in the `&Rc::new(*self)`.
Any ideas, on how each node can keep track of all the other nodes in the network?

Comment: [The code you have provided doesn't produce the errors you say it does](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc7f783815af9888bc7ded39c22f044e&version=stable&mode=debug). Please review how to create a [MCVE] and [edit] your post to contain one.

Answer (score 4):

You should separate your node and your network, because your network *must* take the ownership of your node to create an `Rc` (or at least, it must take an already created `Rc`). Here is a better design that achieves what you want:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::rc::Weak;
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct Network {
    nodes: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Weak<Node>>>>,
}

impl Network {
    fn add_node(&mut self, node: Node) -> Rc<Node> {
        let node = Rc::new(node);
        self.nodes.borrow_mut().push(Rc::downgrade(&node));

        node
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut network = Network::default();
    let node_1 = Node { name: "node_1".into() };
    let node_2 = Node { name: "node_2".into() };

    let _node_1 = network.add_node(node_1);
    let _node_2 = network.add_node(node_2);
}
```

If you want to store a reference to `self`, you can do this:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::rc::Weak;

type MutableNode = Rc<RefCell<Node>>;
type Network = Rc<RefCell<Vec<Weak<RefCell<Node>>>>>;

struct Node {
    name: String,
    others: Network,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(name: String) -> MutableNode {
        let node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            name,
            others: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new())),
        }));
        {
            let tmp = node.borrow();
            tmp.others.borrow_mut().push(Rc::downgrade(&node));
        }

        node
    }

    fn add_node(&mut self, name: String) -> MutableNode {
        let others = self.others.clone();
        let node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node { name, others }));
        self.others
            .borrow_mut()
            .push(Rc::downgrade(&node));

        node
    }

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.others.borrow().len()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let node_0 = Node::new("node_0".into());
    let node_1 = node_0.borrow_mut().add_node("node_1".into());
    let node_2 = node_0.borrow_mut().add_node("node_2".into());

    assert_eq!(node_0.borrow().len(), 3);
    assert_eq!(node_1.borrow().len(), 3);
    assert_eq!(node_2.borrow().len(), 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rc::new(value:T)` consume the `value`.Your function only borrow it, so you can't call `Rc::new(*self)`

I would recommend you to create a Network struct like the above answer. Or you can wrap your node in `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` like this:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::rc::Weak;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    name: String,
    known_nodes: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Weak<RefCell<Node>>>>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn connect_to_network(&mut self,ref_to_self: Weak<RefCell<Node>>) {
        self.known_nodes
            .borrow_mut()
            .push(ref_to_self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let known_nodes = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));
    let node_one = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
        name: "node1".into(),
        known_nodes: known_nodes.clone(),
    }));
    node_one.borrow_mut().connect_to_network(Rc::downgrade(&node_one));
    let node_two = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
        name: "node2".into(),
        known_nodes: known_nodes.clone(),
    }));
    node_two.borrow_mut().connect_to_network(Rc::downgrade(&node_two));
    println!("{:?}",known_nodes.borrow()[0].upgrade());
    println!("{:?}",known_nodes.borrow()[1].upgrade());
    drop(node_one);
    drop(node_two);
    println!("{:?}",known_nodes.borrow()[0].upgrade());
    println!("{:?}",known_nodes.borrow()[1].upgrade());
}
```

Which in this case you don't really need `connect_to_network` function, you can just add each `Weak<RefCell<Node>>` to `known_nodes` directly

If you want the code to look cleaner, you can introduce a new type alias to `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` like this

```
struct Node {
    name: String,
    known_nodes: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Weak<RefCell<Node>>>>>,
}

type RcNode = Rc<RefCell<Node>>;

trait Connectable {
    fn connect_to_network(&self);
}

impl Connectable for RcNode {
    fn connect_to_network(&self){
        let node = self.borrow_mut();
        node.known_nodes.borrow_mut().push(Rc::downgrade(self));
    }
}
```

so then you can call

```
let node_one:RcNode = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
    name: "node1".into(),
    known_nodes: known_nodes.clone(),
}));
node_one.connect_to_network();
```